# How to split string which has different values with multiple delimiters?

Tags: java, regex

Could someone give me suggestions for a regex for the below?

Example: `city^chennai|country^India~TamilNadu|pincode^600034`

Expected delimited String are:

```
city
chennai
country
India,TamilNadu
pincode
600034
```

Note: `~` should be converted into `,`

Comment: cant you use YOUR_STRING_VARIBLE.replace("^"," ").replace("|"," ").replace("~",",")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split on non-word chars (excluding comma) after replacing the `~` with a comma:

```
input.replaceAll("~",",").split("[^\\w,]");
```

then (as per comment requiring a map) iterate over the resulting array in pairs, adding the map entries.

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = "city^chennai|country^India~TamilNadu|pincode^600034";
    String[] things = input.replaceAll( "~", "," ).split( "[^\\w,]" );
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>( );
    for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i+=2) {
        map.put(things[i], things[i+1]);
    }
    System.out.println( map );
}
```

Output:

```
{pincode=600034, country=India,TamilNadu, city=chennai}
```

Comment: I forget to add a point here.. i need to save them as key, value - Map<String, String>.

Comment: I couldn't see the edited answer for Map<String, String>..is the browser refresh problem?

Comment: you can also use shorthand for non-word characters input.replaceAll("~",",").split("[\\W,]");

Comment: @Bala: No, the meaning will be different. His means any except (word character and comma). Yours means (any except word character) and comma, which means any except word character.

Answer (score 0):

```
((w+)[|^~])*(w+)
```

Edit: Now I noticed that it's map-like, so perhaps:

```
((w+)^(w+)|)*(w+)^(w+)
```

Replace w+ with custom class in `[...]` to get ~ also working.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((w+)^(w+)|)*(w+)^(w+)");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("city^chennai|country^India~TamilNadu|pincode^600034");
 if( m.matches() ){
     for( int i = 1; i < m.groupCount(); i+=2 ) {
         // m.group(i) and m.group(i+1) gives you the values.
     }
 }
```

If you want the easier way, use `Pattern#split("")`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could add a small portion of the code snippet.

Comment: Could you please paste the code snippet to understand your approach better?

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do - convert to a different string? Then use regex. Or split and use in java? Then perhaps use the other approach I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
.replaceAll("~", ",").split("[|^]")
```

Assume the String is split up properly, you can group them into name-value pair by mapping the String at index 2k to index (2k + 1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `StringTokenizer` class here to split a string with different delimiters.
Use `hasNextToken("delimiterHereAsString")` method to specify different delimiters with which you want to split.

this link might help you.
http://www.java-examples.com/java-stringtokenizer---specify-delimiter-example